# convert "Thu May 29 2014 12:00:00 GMT-0700" to DateTime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a problem to convert "Thu May 29 2014 12:00:00 GMT-0700"  to DateTime

Error:
I'm sending the value from a hidden field in JS and to the code behind but it keep crashing with the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

```
Dim FromDate As String = hfDateFromByLocation.Value
Dim ToDate As String = hfDateToByLocation.Value

Dim retValFromDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim retValToDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ToDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: well yes yyyy should be after ddd MMM dd shouldn't it!

Comment: Dim retValFromDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "ddd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss KKKK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                Dim retValToDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ToDate, "ddd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss KKKK ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: still getting an error  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Can anyone please show me how to do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to work it out, I got it to work with this format string and using a `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` not a `Datetime`

"ddd MMM dd yyyy H:mm:ss 'GMT'KKKKK"

It's the gmt bit it doesn't like. so I wrapped that in quotes and you need an extra K for the minus sign..

Bit more investigation, you can use DateTime.ParseExact but you lose the time zone offset. The datetime is correct, in that it takes the offset into account, but you don't know how 'much' of it was the offset.

"ddd MMM dd yyyy H:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz" also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't like the "GMT" inside the string:

This code based on Tony Hopkinson's answer:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FromDate As String = "Thu May 29 2014 12:00:00 GMT-0700"
    Dim retValFromDate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'KKKK", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    MsgBox(retValFromDate.ToString)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That'll work I'd have used String.Replace probably and String.substring that old VB6 stuff gives me the heebies

Comment: thank you for your help but its still throwing the same error like before. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Needs another K for the timezone sign at a guess or you could use zzz

Comment: I added another K but no change still the same error... Dim retValFromDate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(RemoveGMT(FromDate), "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss KKKKK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)      I didn't find any solution for that no where.

Comment: User3654570 - check the format string, I moved the YYYY per Tony Hopkinson

Comment: Try the one I posted, worked for me, and you don't need to massage GMT out